Black bars appear in timeline when moving keyframes
Whenever I move a keyframe, these vertical black bars appear near the keyframes in the timeline editor.

Any ideas why this is happening?

You turned on proportional editing in the dopesheet. (Hotkey: O)

Oh, wow. Wasn't aware of that. Thanks

@Leander could you post that as an answer

You turned on proportional editing in the dopesheet. You can toggle the functionality by pressing the hotkey O.
The dopesheet show and icon on the right of the menu bar, that indicates the status of proportional editing.

